# Boundary and limit points

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose that $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that if $\vec{x} \notin \Omega$ and $\vec{x}$ is a boundary point of $\Omega$, then $\vec{x}
$ is a limit point of $\Omega$.

My try:

$\vec{x}$ is a boundary point so there is a ball around it such that there are points in $\Omega$ and $\Omega^c$. We construct a sequence $\{\vec{x}_i\} \in $ the ball around $\vec{x}$ and it converges to $\vec{x}$ since the sequence is within the ball.

I can't think of a technical proof and I'm notconfidence on my answer since the logic seems wrong

ANy help thanks

Comment: why do u use arrow with $x$ ?what is your definition of limit point?

Comment: Because I can't find a faster way to do \textbf{x}. My definition of limit point is if there is a sequence in a set that converges to a particular point. That point is the limit point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{B_i\}$ be a sequence of shrinking open balls around $x$.
Since $x$ is a boundary point, *every* open ball around it contains a point in $\Omega$ (and a point in $\Omega^c$), in particular for each $i$ there is $x_i \in B_i$ such that $x_i \in \Omega$. Each $x_i$ is distinct from $x$ since $x$ is not in $\Omega$, hence $\{x_i\} \subset \Omega$ is a sequence in $\Omega$ converging to $x$ and distinct from $x$, i.e. $x$ is a limit point of $\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. That idea of shrinking open balls helped me understand why there is a sequence that converges to $x$.